# can not make call to Controller function via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-handling, cakephp-3.0

I know similar question has been answered in this forum. I have tried many of the solutions provided in stackoverflow for the problem, yet could not solve it. So I am expecting some suggestions from your expertise.

I am trying to make a call to AjaxController function on form submit via ajax call using Cakephp 3. The issue here is i am getting 403 error. I have not yet found out the fix for this. I can see that form is passing the value but Ajax call can not reach the controller function . I get following error

**POST http://localhost/shoppingCart/ajax/ajaxTest 403 (Forbidden)**

AjaxController:

```
 public function ajaxTest(){
    $result = "hello";
    return $result;


}

    script:(view.ctp of AjaxController)

     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function(event){
              var form_data = $(this).serialize();
              var hidden_value = $('[name="id"]').val();
                  // alert("your form data "+hidden_value);//works fine here
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                      url:'../ajaxTest',
                      type:'POST',
                      data : hidden_value,
                      success:function(result){
                        alert('success');
                          $("#result").text(result);
                      },

                      error:function(error){

                        alert('error ='+(error.Message));
                      }
              });

            });
        });

        //  });
    </script>
```

Comment: Whats your route for the ajax controller

Comment: http://localhost/shoppingCart/ajax/ajaxTest is exact route

Comment: The one in the config/routes file

Comment: Did you mean this ???$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'ajax', 'action' => 'index']);

Comment: Yes do you have one configured for ajaxtest

Answer (score 0):

According to Cakephp:

> If authenticator returns null, AuthComponent redirects user to the
>   login action. If it’s an AJAX request and config ajaxLogin is
>   specified that element is rendered else a 403 HTTP status code is
>   returned.

I think you didn't specify any authorization scheme. That why according to cakephp you are getting 403 error.

> If you don’t use an authorization scheme, make sure to check
>   authorization yourself in your controller’s beforeFilter or with
>   another component.

You can make actions public (in beforeFilter or initialize) using:

```
// Allow all actions
$this->Auth->allow();

// Allow only the index action.
$this->Auth->allow('ajaxTest');

// Allow only the view and index actions.
$this->Auth->allow(['ajaxTest', 'index']);
```

[CakePhp > Authentication > Handling Unauthenticated Requests](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#handling-unauthenticated-requests)

[CakePhp > Authentication > Using No Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#handling-unauthenticated-requests)

Comment: finally solved! there was problem with csrf token. (totally no idea at all!). So what i did was i obtained the token from request object in my view file and used it in my Ajax like this:   `var csrfToken = <?php echo(json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken'))) ?>;   $.ajax({
                headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken },
}`